# Unable to delete rows through php, HTML

Tags: php, html

I am just unable to understand why the rows are not getting deleted!
please note that i am getting the login values of corrected check boxes in the php page.
from my point of view, most probably error should be in php page where i am using 
'DELETE FROM' query.

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <form id="delete_customers" action="deletecustomers.php" method="post">
    <?php
      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
      mysql_select_db("car_rental_system", $con);
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer");

      echo "<table border='1' align='center'>
              <tr>
                <th>first_name</th>
                <th>Last_name</th>
                <th>login</th>
              </tr>";

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['login'] . "</td>";

        echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' name='deletingcustomers[]'
                    value=$row['login']}"."</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";

      mysql_close($con);
    ?>
    <p class='submit'>
      <button type='submit' name='dscustomer'>Delete selected</button>
    </p>
  </head>
</html>
```

//NOW deletecustomers.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['deletingcustomers'] = $_POST['deletingcustomers'];
  $N = count($_SESSION['deletingcustomers']);
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("car_rental_system", $con);

  if(empty($_SESSION['deletingcustomers'])) {
    echo("No customers selected");
  } else {
    for ($i=0; $i<$N; $i++) {
      $sql1="delete from `customer` 
               where login='{$_SESSION[deletingcustomers][$i]}'";
      if(mysql_query($sql1,$con))
        echo 'executed';
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: Not to mention your code is vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: Also, PDO is REALLY EASY.  Thought I might throw that out there.

Comment: @Daedalus: There's a new version of this comment, go to PHP chat to update :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' name='deletingcustomers[]' value=$row['login']}"."</td>";

To

    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='deletingcustomers[]' value='".$row['login']."'</td>";
```

**and try**

Comment: AWESOME yar:D:D
that worked liked a charm, i almost broke my head doing it last night!
Drake pointed out some really good matter too, it will be fun reading that , definitely more advanced than w3:)

Comment: sorry cant vote up,
very new to stack overflow so dont have enough reputation:/

Answer (score 3):

NO! No! Why do people keep using mysql_query().....(head desk)

Please look up PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php it helps prevent sql injections and gives you a better understanding of how to harness oop's power.

Your `$_SESSION[deletingcustomers][$i]` needs to be `$_SESSION['deletingcustomers'][$i]`

Example on its way

```
$tempVar = $_SESSION['deletingcustomers'][$i];
$dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=".$hostName.";dbname=".$dbName, $username, $password);
$sql = "delete from `customer` where login='$tempVar'";
$stmt = $newObj->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: this should be a comment. It's not an answer. No downvote yet :)

Comment: It's because this type of code is so prevalent in search results and nobody actually researched the *right* way to do things (or reads docs for that matter)

Comment: This is also part of the reason there are **so** many bad PHP developers out in the wild.

Comment: @codingbiz you are too kind :) sberry, I know its so ridiculous. I think its a bunch of new people reading old documentation like w3schools... #HATEw3schools

Comment: @JaredDrake 
thnx for the reply.
i will definitely look forward for reading the linked pages you provided.
coming back to the error you pointed, it still is not deleting.
next thing, what does the 5th statement in your code doing?

Comment: @anshul Gupta that would actually be a copy and paste typo :( lol its fixed. Basically, you prep the query then you finally tell it to run with execute();

Comment: @JaredDrake In your example, your code is vulnerable to injection attacks with the way you've wrote it, which kind of defeats the purpose of pdo.